# Разница между сервисом и винформ приложением

Tags: c#

Есть программа (для опроса опс серверов). Если её запустить как приложение винформ то опрос идет, а если тот же код закинуть в сервис, то пишет null reference object

Comment: Без кода сложно сказать. Просто копи\пастом вряд ли получится запустить удаленный объект)

Comment: Пока телепаты не подтянулись, может, вы расскажете нам, какой именно объект в случае сервиса `null` и откуда он берётся?

Comment: На основе того что сказано предположу, что проблема в том, что Windows Service не имеет **GUI** а ваше приложение его использует. Некоторую информацию об ограничениях можно взять отсюда http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353

Comment: А телепаты смотрю подтягиваются =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем все просто. В настройках сервис указать вход от имени и ставить логин\пасс админа